# Как расставить запятые в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Как расставить запятые в следующем предложении?

*Орфография хромает практически через каждый комментарий.*

Answer (score 2):

Никаких запятых в этом предложении ставить не нужно.

Если же при произнесении имеется явная пауза (или автор текста хочет показать эту паузу), то запятая допустима. Тогда ***практически через каждый комментарий*** будет присоединительной конструкцией. Предложение можно даже разделить на два:

*Орфография хромает. Практически через каждый комментарий.*

Можно и так: *Орфография хромает... практически через каждый комментарий.*

Answer (score 1):

Запятые здесь не нужны, так как нет ни подчинительных связей, ни однородных членов. При большом желании влепить хоть какой-то знак препинания допустимо, например вставить интонационное тире после "хромает", но реальной нужды в нём нет.